# How to display name instead of id using active admin in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, activeadmin

Hi I'm working on a Rails *3.2.9* app which uses *devise* and *ActiveAdmin*. I have models like users and company. I want admin to select one manager from list of registered users for a particular company.

My user's table has these fields : id,username, email, company_id, password etc

My company's table has : id, company_name, manager_id (this is nothing but id of user), created_at etc

After the admin has selected a manager for a company , i want his name(username from users table) to appear in the index page for company but now only manager_id is shown in index page. (On edit, the dropdown for selecting manager shows list of usernames)

Pls let me know how to use a query/joins statement to accomplish this

Here's my **companies.rb** file for admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  index do
    column "Company", :name
    column :address
    column "No. of Subscriptions", :no_of_licenses
    column "Manager", :manager_id
    default_actions
  end
  filter :name

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Company Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :address
      f.input :no_of_licenses, :label => 'No of Subscriptions'
      f.input :manager_id, :as => :select, :collection => User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON users.company_id = companies.id').map{|u| [u.username, u.id]} 
    end
    f.buttons
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by @Bunty, we should pass the user record to the manager column. The following code worked!!

```
 column "Manager" do |m|
   usr = User.find(m.manager_id).username
 end
```

This now displays the name of manager rather than manager_id like before

Answer (score 11):

Since you have used manager_id instead of user_id, active admin consider it as a single integer value.

To get fetch record automatic using id you can generate migration and change column as user_id.

If you dont want to change column name in then pass the if to User record as,

```
column "Manager" do |m|
  usr = User.find(m.manager_id)
  link_to usr.title, admin_user_path(m.manager_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! This worked except that the link to gave error and first line was returning an object id. I modified this a bit and it works.I'll update in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the method `display_name` on the model. That way the name of the model is overridden in all the views. I like that more than fiddling with the form.